# After ajax submit: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: jquery, ajax, cdata

i have an error in this code
I tried with cdata but not working. **Thank you for your help**

```
    $(document).ready(function webservice(){ 

        $.mobile.loading( 'show', {
         text: 'Start application...',
         textVisible: true,
         theme: 'a',
         html: ""
        });

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "//webservice.domain.ltd/connect/app/device.asmx",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(response) {
        var redirect = response.getHeader('Location');
        document.location = redirect;
        }

        });

});
```

Comment: Check the JSONP, that is returned. Probably there is an error in it, which prevents the parsing.

Comment: You can check the JSONP by using the Network tab in most Developer Tools available in your browser nowadays